# getopts doesn't execute some flags

Tags: shell, zsh, getopts

I am writing a zsh script to make easier the use of the `git clone` command. The `-h` and `-s` flags works fine, but the `-d` and `-q` flags don't. I tried to see if they worked by adding `echo $dir` and `echo $quiet`, but I've got nothing in result (they were empty).

I wanted to use the flags and the out-of-the-box method.
This is the code I wrote:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/zsh

# Git clone
function clone() {
    usage=("Usage: $0 [-h http] [-s ssh] [-d dir] -q

Options:
    -h  Use the http protocol to clone the git repo (https://github.com/<your repository>)
    -s  Use ssh to clone the git repo (git@github.com:<your repository>)
    -d  Destination Directory
    -q  Quiet clone")
    githttp=(git clone https://github.com/)
    gitssh=(git clone git@github.com:)
    while getopts ":h:s:d:q:" opt; do
        case "$opt" in
            h) http=$OPTARG
               $quiet $githttp$http $dir
               return $?
               ;;
            s) ssh=$OPTARG
               $quiet $gitssh$ssh $dir
               return $?
               ;;
            d) dir=$OPTARG 
               ;;
            q) quiet=(gum spin)
               ;;
            *) echo "Invalid option"
               echo $usage
               return 1
               ;;
        esac
    done

    method=$(gum choose "http" "ssh")
    case "$method" in
        http) http=$(gum input --prompt=" " --placeholder="Type url here")
              dir=$(gum input --prompt=" " --placeholder="Type here the directory. Leave blank for current")
              if [[ -z $http || -z $dir ]]; then
                echo "Exiting..."
                return 1
              else
                $githttp$http $dir
              fi
              ;;
        ssh)  ssh=$(gum input --prompt=" " --placeholder="")
              dir=$(gum input --prompt=" " --placeholder="Type here the directory. Leave blank for current")
              if [[ -z $ssh || -z $dir ]]; then
                echo "Exiting..."
                return 1
              else
                $gitssh$ssh $dir
              fi
              ;;
        *)    echo "Exiting..."
              return 1
              ;;
    esac
}
```

How can I fix this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: In bash, the answer is to localize OPTIND and OPTARG inside functions: `local OPTIND OPTARG`. I don't the zsh-specific command.

Comment: Do you have an example invocation demonstrating the error? With the `return` statements for `h)` and `s)`, the loop and function are going to exit when those options are in the input. If the input is similar to the usage statement, with `-d` and `-q` at the end, those options will be skipped.

Comment: @Gairfowl Sorry for the late reply, I tried to echo the variable when it clones the repo, but it returns nothing. 
Here are two screenshots of the code and the output:
[https://imgur.com/a/yWepHLW](https://imgur.com/a/yWepHLW)
-- edit
I forgot to use the `-q` flag in the image, but the result is the same.

Comment: @Gairfowl I noticed that if I exclude the rest of the code and leave only the loop, it returns `Too many arguments`. Is something wrong in the flags?
[Photo](https://imgur.com/a/98TPh7E)

Comment: Try changing the order of the options: `clone -d test -s charm...`; you'll likely find that makes a difference. To avoid requiring a specific order in the options, you can move the `git` executions and `return` statements out of the loop, and just use the `while getopts` loop to set variables.

Comment: Your optstring discards all errors and requires an argument for `-q`, which I don't think you want. Perhaps you're running `-q -d` in which case `d` is an argument to `-q`? What happens when you remove the leading and trailing colons, changing it to `getopts h:s:d:q opt`?